# Can't init firebase on iOS in Unity without having an Android project

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine

I've tried initializing Firebase on Unity for iOS app only, and I'm getting this error while running:

> Unable to load options for default app ([/Users/yaniv/Downloads/21312111222/New Unity Project333/Assets/StreamingAssets/google-services-desktop.json, /Users/yaniv/Downloads/21312111222/New Unity Project333/Assets/StreamingAssets/google-services.json] are missing or malformed)

I know that for cross-platform apps, I usually download the google-services.json from the Firebase project settings, but in this case, I have no Android apps under this project (it's an iOS app only).

How can I prevent Firebase from request it?